# Транспонировать список списков и напечатать в виде красивой таблицы. (Печать списков в столбцах)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Добрый день, поговорим о красивой печати списков в `Python`.
Есть список списков

```
list = [['x', 'y', 'z'],
       ['x1', 'y1', 'z1'],
       ['x2', 'y2', 'z2']]
```

Подскажите, как сделать так, чтобы вывод был похож на этот:

```
x x1 x2
y y1 y2
z z1 z2
```

Интересует именно как заставить python выводить списки по вертикали и, при этом, последующий список разместить правее, а не под первым.

Comment: связанный вопрос [Matrix Transpose in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4937491/4279)

Comment: связанный вопрос [Fast matrix transposition in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921681/fast-matrix-transposition-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

Можно траспонировать матрицу при помощи `zip(*lst)` и использовать модуль [`tabulate`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tabulate) для красивой печати:

```
In [125]: from tabulate import tabulate

In [127]: print(tabulate(list(zip(*lst)), tablefmt='simple'))
-  --  --
x  x1  x2
y  y1  y2
z  z1  z2
-  --  --

In [128]: print(tabulate(list(zip(*lst)), tablefmt='plain'))
x  x1  x2
y  y1  y2
z  z1  z2

In [129]: print(tabulate(list(zip(*lst)), tablefmt='grid'))
+---+----+----+
| x | x1 | x2 |
+---+----+----+
| y | y1 | y2 |
+---+----+----+
| z | z1 | z2 |
+---+----+----+

In [130]: print(tabulate(list(zip(*lst)), tablefmt='fancy_grid'))
╒═══╤════╤════╕
│ x │ x1 │ x2 │
├───┼────┼────┤
│ y │ y1 │ y2 │
├───┼────┼────┤
│ z │ z1 │ z2 │
╘═══╧════╧════╛
```